# Worpress comment error "You are posting comments too quickly. Slow down"

Tags: wordpress

Here are my problems, recently I and my users are getting this error while posting comments.

Error message: "You are posting comments too quickly. Slow down"
Not just it, I can't see comments but count is increasing in dashboard.
Also people can't contact me via contact form page, which also show error.

After this I had taken this actions:

1. Deactivated theme and plugins.
2. Replaced with native theme and no plugins, but did not solved the issue.
3. Upgraded WordPress, Apache, PHP, MySQL etc.
4. Upgraded my theme and plugins.
5. Checked my server DNS and other settings.
6. Used online current method. Link: https://ihrinnovationgroup.com/solved-you-are-posting-comments-too-quickly-slow-down-wordpress-warning/
7. Shutdown cloudflare.

Here is my doubt, I believe wordpress come with by default anti spam or aksimat moduls. Who some how triggered by flood of spam comments. Or some how firewall got activated. I dont know further stuff !

My website [removed address] is hosted in DigitalOcean cloud server.
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS 64, PHP 7.2.24, MySQL 14.14, Apache 2.4.29

[image: description]

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This doesn't appear to be a programming-related question so it is off topic for this site. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme’s functions.php:

```
add_filter('comment_flood_filter', '__return_false');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).